# SKTexture wrongly recognizes .pvrtc texture size used with SceneKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, pvrtc

I've tried `texturetool` and GUI of `PVRTexTool` to generate .pvrtc texture with 4 bit per pixel format to be loaded with SceneKit via Swift through `SKTexture`, then finally be supplied to use as diffuse texture for `SCNSphere` like following code

```
let diffuse_cloudTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dc_4096.pvr")
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = SKTexture(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 4096, height: 2048), in: diffuse_cloudTexture)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "normal")
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = false
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.shininess = 10
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.isLitPerPixel = true
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
... <other unrelated code left out>
```

> I specified `CGRect` above to specify sub-texture inside. I included 2 textures inside the source texture to be generated. Upper is cloud texture, and lower is diffuse texture.

For `texturetool` I used the following command

```
texturetool -e PVRTC --channel-weighting-linear --bits-per-pixel-4 -o dc_4096.pvrtc -f PVR -p dc_4096_preview.png source_4096.png
```

For `PVRTexTool` I did try both formats => PVRTC 4bpp, and PVRTCII 4bpp both for OpenGL 2.0.

> One notable difference is this tool generated into .pvr but the former generated into .pvrtc. Thus I use corresponding suffix in code as such depending on which tool used to generate such texture.

No matter what I do, it's all empty and transparent. The sphere has no texture.
From debugging log, I print out something via

```
print(diffuse_cloudTexture.debugDescription)
print(diffuse_cloudTexture.textureRect())
print(diffuse_cloudTexture.size())
```

and it shows

```
<SKTexture> 'dc_4096.pvr' (128 x 128)
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(128.0, 128.0)
top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0
```

why it recognizes only 128x128 in size. I instead have 4096x4096 in size.

---

In additional, if use use the following code instead

```
let diffuse_cloudTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dc_4096.pvr")
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = diffuse_cloudTexture
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "normal")
```

It shows weird result as follows.

[image]

It should be normal globe texture.

---

What might be the problem? and How can I use .pvrtc texture with SceneKit no matter through SKTexture or not?

**edit**

(searching for solution is still developing)

- firstly thanks to @KnightOfDragon as seen in the comment. Weird texture as loaded is default X image when it cannot find texture to load. Now I see `SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "dc_4096.pvrtc"`. So that 128x128 resolution of texture should be of that X default image.
- That's right. Seems like `SKTexture` doesn't support .pvr type as @KnightOfDragon pointed me in the comment. So I just tried to use `MTLTexture` via `MTKTextureLoader` and be able to render texture onto sphere now. The problem i'm facing next is how to grab just partial of full texture in the same way that `SKTexture` can do via `SKTexture(rect: ...<rect to grab>, in: ...<SKTexture>...)`. The clue I got to know `MTLTexture` supports .pvr is looking at list of pixel format it supports [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlpixelformat).

Comment: Did you check if the asset manager loaded it correctly?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I checked, it included in bundle properly. I put .pvrtc in .scnassets directory. As well as able to print out debugging info of loaded texture as I mentioned in the question using `SKTexture`.

Comment: Scnassets?  you are using SpriteKit texture,  wouldn't you want to add it to XCAssets and it would show you.  You could also add a regular image and then specify what type of compression you want the image to have and let XCode handle it for you, instead of having to worry about external compression,  Also, I can't find any documentation that states SKTexture takes pvrct,  so it may be treating it as a raw image file.  Is the file size by chance 32KB?

Comment: I tried as your suggestion. Put it inside normal xcassets (but compression options has no .pvr stuff) and load via `SKTexture` (it still detected 128x128 resolution instead of 4096x4096), and finally it shows nothing the same.

You're right about `SKTexture`, I didn't find it mentions about pvr as well. File size is in > 8 MB.

Comment: Well the compression techniques use plain english.  I think GPU smallest is RGBA4444

Comment: OH i know what is happening,  SKTexture defaults to an X image if no texture is found.  You are loading that X image, and wrapping it in a sphere

Comment: I would recommend just taking your source.png and putting that into xcassets, and play with the compression as you best see fit

Comment: Oh dang, it indeeds looks like X image. Yes, it wraps around sphere. Ideal is I would like to have .pvr as it has 4 bit per pixel. I have several textures, and really like to reduce memory usage. Anyway, I'm testing your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, xcassets does the compression for you, so you see the original, then during build phase, it compresses